# Is there a general expression similar in meaning to "at the rate things are going" or "at the rate at which x is going"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Notice that those expressions are specifically about rate. 
Like "if the way things have gone so far mean anything" but less awkward. Like "the way things have gone so far" but with the implication that this pattern has inertia.

Comment: Could you put the phrase into a complete example sentence so we can see what sort of thing you mean?  Also, do you want a technical term? slang? something else?

Comment: "Based on the way things have gone so far" implies that things are likely to continue going in that direction. This already embodies the concept of inertia.

Comment: “The way things are going”, we are likely to run out of money by July.

Comment: There is nothing particular ratish about "At this rate ..."

Comment: To add to the previous comment, [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at-this-rate) of _at this rate_ and the accompanying example do suggest _inertia_.